# How can I read (save) different lines (of numeric values) of a csv file into different arrays in C#

Tags: c#

I am new in C# and trying to build a sort of calculator application that will read values from a csv file and then carry on with the manipulation that's needed.

the calculator algorithm is working fine but I need to populate the arrays from a csv file. I have used StreamReader as follows but it puts all values into a single array:

```
FileStream aFile = new FileStream("d:\test.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(aFile);
                strLine = sr.ReadLine();
               while (strLine != null)
                {
                    strArray = strLine.Split(charArray);
                    for (int x = 1; x <= strArray.GetUpperBound(0); x++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(strArray[x].Trim());
```

I need to read seperate lines into separate arrays and these lines can be dynamic (i.e. csv files can have n number of lines which will require n arrays). The calculator algorithm is below and is working fine. I only need how to use the above code to read csv into arrays and use those arrays in the code below (code below, though an excerpt, is working fine). Any help please.

```
for (int p = 0; p < n; p++)   
       { 
         for (int j = 0; j < t; j++)
            {
                sum[j] = w[p, j] * a[p, j];
                k[p] = k[p] + sum[j];
            }
        }
        double loa=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            loa1[i] = k[i] * v[i];
            loa += loa1[i];
```

Comment: You need to fix the formatting of your code. I was going to edit the post, but I can't figure out what you're doing. You're using your inner `i` indexer before you even declare it in your `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

The [TextFieldParser](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fmicrosoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx&ei=rH5sUNbEA-Tm0QH6qYGYCg&usg=AFQjCNE7Y0l9fyFsKpZQCr66e6ZYWWkohw) class is great for reading CSV files.

```
TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser("filename.txt");
parser.Delimiters = new[] { "," };
while (!parser.EndOfData)
{
    string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
    //process this line of fields, or store it for later processing
}
```

You can then use `int.TryParse` or `double.TryParse` to turn the appropriate strings into numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks all for your comments and help -very much appreciated. I was able to read lines separately using:

```
using (TextFieldParser fieldParser = new TextFieldParser(name)) "d:\\test1.txt"))
        {
          parts = fieldParser.ReadFields();
```

and then hold the values from separate lines in an double array using:

```
double[] array = Array.ConvertAll(parts, double.Parse);
```

and then I used a counter and EndOfData property to manage line switches that define separate arrays:

```
counter++;
if (fieldParser.EndOfData)
                {
```

Thanks again. may calculator is now working and is available at http://thaddeus-eze.com